# How to close a socket connection when exiting your account

Tags: socket.io, nestjs

I am the server side I use nestjs. I created the app.gateway file and created the functions of connecting and disconnecting from the socket in it.

```
@WebSocketGateway()
export class AppGateway implements OnGatewayInit, OnGatewayConnection, OnGatewayDisconnect {
    private logger: Logger = new Logger(AppGateway.name);

    afterInit(): void {
        this.logger.log('Chat listening events');
    }

    handleConnection(@ConnectedSocket() client: Socket): void {
        this.logger.log(`Client connected: ${client.id}`);
    }

    handleDisconnect(@ConnectedSocket() client: Socket): void {
        this.logger.log(`Client disconnected: ${client.id}`);
    }
}
```

Then I created a controller in which I implemented a method for exiting.

```
@ApiUseTags('auth')
@Controller('auth')
export class AuthController {
    constructor(
        private readonly tokenService: TokenService,
    ) {}

    private readonly logger = new Logger(AuthController.name);

    @UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'))
    @Post('/logout')
    public async logout(@Response() res, @Request() req): Promise<object> {
        this.logger.log('Logout');
        const user: IUser = req.user;
        await this.tokenService.daleteTokenByUserId(user.id);
        return res.status(HttpStatus.OK).json({ success: true });
    }
}
```

How can I disconnect a socket connection in my controller when the client calls the logout method?

Comment: I've added an answer, I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#socket-close) you can use either `socket.close()` or `socket.disconnect()`.